# Bit level representation of Strings in Java

Tags: java, string, char

I know that a string is a sequence of characters. But how is it represented in bit-level? Is it the same like representing a character? Like, is the string `"ab"` represented as `0000000001100001 0000000001100010` where the first 16 bits represents the Unicode number of `a` and the second 16 bits represents the Unicode number of `b`?

Comment: Perhaps you should read this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding

Comment: Ok, I just figured out that you can use some characters whose Unicode no is above \uffff by using this notation in string "\uxxxx\uxxxx". So, you cannot represent these characters as char but you can surely represent these characters as strings. So, anyone to help for the bit-level representation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But how is it represented in bit-level? Is it the same like representing a character?

Not necessarily.  It depends on the version of Java that you are using, and other things.

- Prior to Java 9, the *default* character content of a `String` was represented as an array of `char`.  So your example representation would be essentially correct for Java 8 and earlier.
- Between Java 6 and Java 8, there was a JVM option to enable "compressed strings".  This used 1 byte per character for strings that consisted only of ASCII characters.  The representation of a string with this feature enabled used either a `byte[]` or a `char[]`.
- In Java 9, they introduced "compact string" support as standard.  This does roughly the same thing as "compressed strings", but with some important differences that made it a more effective optimization.  (The actual data type used is a `byte[]`.  In the case where the characters in the string are 16 bit, each pair of `byte` values represents a `char`.

With both "compressed" and "compact" strings, the representation will depend on the actual characters.  For your `"ab"` example, the bit-level representation will be 2 bytes rather than 2 16-bit words.

You also asked if String supports code-points larger than U+FFFF.  The answer is Yes.  When `char[]` representations are used (as they would be here), the code-points are actually encoded in UTF-16.  This means that a code point greater than U+FFFF is represented as two 16-bit code units.  (A surrogate pair.)